# Creating excell file with Django workbook and worksheet

Tags: django, excel, python-2.7, worksheet

I am trying to create excell report with django workbook and workseet as below.

```
def print_assistant_notes(request):
if request.method == 'GET':
    notes = AssistantNotes.objects.filter(notedate=datetime.today().date()).order_by("time")
    workbook = load_workbook(os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, "export_templates", "assistant_notes.xlsx"))
    worksheet = workbook.active
    title_cell = worksheet["A%d" % (1,)]
    title_cell.value = "Assistant Notes [ "+str(datetime.today().date())+" ] "
    row = 3
    for note in notes:
        time_cell = worksheet["A%d" % (row,)]
        category_cell = worksheet["B%d" % (row,)]
        note_cell = worksheet["C%d" % (row,)]

        time_cell.value = note.time
        category_cell.value = note.categories
        note_cell.value = note.dailynote

        row = row + 1
    tmp_file = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
    workbook.save(tmp_file.name)
    response = HttpResponse(smart_str(tmp_file.read()), content_type='application/vnd.ms-excel')
    response["Content-Disposition"] = 'attachment; filename="assistant_notes.xlsx"'
    return response
```

When i print report i get excell report as below in red color data. But i want it to be formatted as blue colored format. Because notes colum does not fit in print area as i mentioned it with blue arrow.
So i can say that my codes are generating report as the red part.
But i want it to fit in the printable area in blue part. So i want to be able to set cell sizes. And text will fit in that cell size left to right. Up to down cell size will be dynamic as text size may change.

[image]

Comment: which python package are you using (where does `load_workbook` come from?)

Comment: Hi, it is coming from "from openpyxl import load_workbook"

Comment: then how about `note_cell.alignment = Alignment(wrap_text=True)`?

Comment: Exception Value: global name 'Alignment' is not defined

Comment: of course you need to import it first: `from openpyxl.styles import Alignment`

Comment: Perfect. Thank you so much. You can add it as an answer if you want. How did you find that you have to import and use Alignment ?

Comment: See my answer below, there's a link to the docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `openpyxl`, you can actually change the styles of your cells, as outlined in the [documentation](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/styles.html#cell-styles):

```
from openpyxl.styles import Alignment

note_cell.alignment = Alignment(wrap_text=True)
```

Or create an `alignment` object before your `for...` loop and reuse it:

```
al = Alignment(wrap_text=True)
for note in notes:
    ...
    note_cell = worksheet["C%d" % (row,)]
    note_cell.alignment = al
```

which will be more memory-efficient.